# Can't verify signatures with nuget

Tags: nuget, signature, signing

I have a package that I signed with my own certificate, issued by my own CA.

I signed a nuget package with the certificate.

When I add the root CA in the trust store of the machine, I can verify the signature successfully with nuget, using

```
nuget verify test.nupkg -Signatures
```

But, if I remove the root from the trust store, and instead, I add the thumbprint of my certificate as a trusted signers, in nuget, setting `allowUntrustedRoot` to true, I cannot verify the signature, for some reason.

```
> nuget trusted-signers 
Registered trusted signers: 


 1.   MyCert [author] 
      Certificate fingerprint(s): 
        [U] SHA256 - 39544DEE346D61EB2FF5CF4A35EF4B42DE5B4641E1B9AAA098A2A5291F683631
```

But

```
> nuget verify test.nupkg -Signatures 

Verifying Test 
C:\test.nupkg 

Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256 
WARNING: NU3027: The signature should be timestamped to enable long-term signature validity after the certificate has expired. 
Signature type: Author 
Verifying the author primary signature with certificate: 
  Subject Name: CN=Test Certificate, OU=Test, C=BE 
  SHA1 hash: 679B1E503720C69D981B9CC4F0199D5D8593375A 
  SHA256 hash: 39544DEE346D61EB2FF5CF4A35EF4B42DE5B4641E1B9AAA098A2A5291F683631 
  Issued by: CN=Test Root, OU=Test, O=Test, C=BE 
  Valid from: 10/31/2019 10:29:54 AM to 9/24/2023 11:37:39 AM 

NU3018: The author primary signature found a chain building issue: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider. 
WARNING: NU3018: The author primary signature found a chain building issue: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server could not be reached. For more information, visit https://aka.ms/certificateRevocationMode. 
WARNING: NU3018: The author primary signature found a chain building issue: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate. 
Finished with 1 errors and 3 warnings. 

Package signature validation failed.
```

What's the point of adding a trusted signer and setting `allowUntrustedRoot` to true if the signature is not verify. I mean, it's apparently enough to add the root certificate to the trust store for the signature to be verified, without doing anything with the configuration.
I would like, if possible, to be able to not import the root CA in the trust store, and only use the configuration of Nuget to verify successfully the signature.

Thanks.

Comment: This issue addressed recently. For more details: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/4396 It'll be in next release .net sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Our belief is that if you tried to use that package in a project with those trust policy settings appropriately in nuget.configs, restore will succeed.
Please confirm that.

Next, nuget verify has a -config switch -- please try passing in the path to your nuget.config.

If the first test works, and the second test doesn't, nuget may have a bug in the verify command. If so, please file an issue at https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/

-Rob Relyea (NuGet Client Team)